# How to find the number of rows and columns in a table image with Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How can we get the number of rows and columns in an Image table via OpenCV.

Code for getting boxes in table which I am getting right

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_final_bin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
# initialize the reverse flag and sort index
reverse = False
i = 0
# handle if we need to sort in reverse
if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
    reverse = True
# handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
# the x-coordinate of the bounding box
if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
    i = 1
# construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
# bottom
boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
(cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
    key=lambda b:b[1][i], reverse=reverse))
# return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
return (cnts, boundingBoxes)

(contours, boundingBoxes) = sort_contours(contours, method="top-to-bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your sample image to the post :)

Comment: Cant upload the exact file due to restrictions but here is the example image. Need to convert this image in pandas dataframe. Have extracted boxes from the image with help of above code and also extracted matter in these with help of tesserocr. If we can know the number of columns and rows in exact number we can make empty data frame in pandas and then put boxes data in the pandas table, thus getting pandas table from image. Please suggest if there is any other way to get pandas table from this image.

Answer (score 7):

Here are two methods: The first uses the structure of the table to determine the number of rows and columns while the second uses cell count.

**Method #1: Table structure**

The idea is that we can count the number of horizontal and vertical lines of the table to determine the number of rows and columns. For rows, it's `rows = horizontal lines - 1` and for columns, it's `columns = vertical lines - 1`.

Detected horizontal lines in green

[image]

Detected vertical lines in green

[image]

Result

```
Rows: 7
Columns: 4
```

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find number of rows 
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))
horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
rows = 0
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)
    rows += 1

# Find number of columns
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,25))
vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
columns = 0
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)
    columns += 1

print('Rows:', rows - 1)
print('Columns:', columns - 1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

**Method #2: Cell count**

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load image, convert to grayscale, [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization).
2. **Remove text inside cells.** Find contours and filter using [`cv2.contourArea()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to remove text by filling in the contours with [`cv2.drawContours()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html)
3. **Invert image.** We invert the image so the cells are in white and the background in black
4. **Sort cells and sum rows/columns.** We [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then sort the contours from `top-to-bottom` using [`imutils.contours.sort_contours`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py#L7). Next we iterate through contours and find the [centroid](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to obtain the `(cX, cY)` coordinates. The idea is that we can compare the `cY` value of each cell to determine if it is a new row or a cell in the same row by using a offset. A cell should be in the same row if the `cY` value is +/- some offset value. If it is greater then it means the cell is in a new row. We build a model table where the length of the table gives you the rows while the length of any index gives you the number of columns.

---

Binary image

[image]

Removed text contours + inverted image

[image]

Here's a visualization of iterating through each cell to count the number of rows and columns

[image]

Result

```
Rows: 7
Columns: 4
```

Code

```
import numpy as np
from imutils import contours
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and remove text inside cells
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 4000:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)

# Invert image
invert = 255 - thresh
offset, old_cY, first = 10, 0, True
visualize = cv2.cvtColor(invert, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Find contours, sort from top-to-bottom and then sum up column/rows
cnts = cv2.findContours(invert, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="top-to-bottom")
for c in cnts:
    # Find centroid
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    
    # New row
    if (abs(cY) - abs(old_cY)) > offset:
        if first:
            row, table = [], []
            first = False
        old_cY = cY
        table.append(row)
        row = []
    
    # Cell in same row
    if ((abs(cY) - abs(old_cY)) <= offset) or first:
        row.append(1)
   
    # Uncomment to visualize 
    '''
    cv2.circle(visualize, (cX, cY), 10, (36, 255, 12), -1) 
    cv2.imshow('visualize', visualize)
    cv2.waitKey(200)
    '''

print('Rows: {}'.format(len(table)))
print('Columns: {}'.format(len(table[1])))

cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: how we have decided the area which is 4000 here

Comment: That can be any predetermined threshold area value. Its just filter out any small particles of noise

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an easy solution would be to first look left to right and check if each pixel is black (which would indicate that we have found a column. Then do the same for rows (if from top to bottom each pixel is black, it means it has found a row).

One complication is the width of the line which means you will count it as only 1 row/column found until it finds white color.

I could work out the code for this but I'm not at home right now, so maybe someone else can write the code and I will delete my answer later. I know this could be a comment but I don't have 50 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

One other approach is first to verify if its a real table or not, For that hough's line transform can be used, once it is done you can use the approach explained above by fellow.