# Determining the number of columns within a newspaper article

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

Let's imagine the following newspaper article needs to be analyzed regarding the amount of columns (the solution should be 3 text columns). I tried to retrieve the amount of columns using the cv2 library with python and found the following suggestion on StackOverflow: [Detect number of rows and columns in table image with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396925/detect-number-of-rows-and-columns-in-table-image-with-opencv)

[image: Example of a newspaper article]

However, as the table of that solution is well structured, the amount of columns and rows can be extracted quite easily. Based on that solution, here is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
from imutils import contours
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('example_newspaper_article.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and remove text inside cells
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 10000:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), 30)

# Invert image
invert = thresh
offset, old_cY, first = 10, 0, True
visualize = cv2.cvtColor(invert, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Find contours, sort from top-to-bottom and then sum up column/rows
cnts = cv2.findContours(invert, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="top-to-bottom")
for c in cnts:
    # Find centroid
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    # New row
    if (abs(cY) - abs(old_cY)) > offset:
        if first:
            row, table = [], []
            first = False
        old_cY = cY
        table.append(row)
        row = []
    # Cell in same row
    if ((abs(cY) - abs(old_cY)) <= offset) or first:
        row.append(1)
    # Uncomment to visualize
    #cv2.circle(visualize, (cX, cY), 10, (36, 255, 12), -1)
    #cv2.imshow('visualize', visualize)
    #cv2.waitKey(200)

print('Rows: {}'.format(len(table)))
print('Columns: {}'.format(len(table[1])))

cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I thought, that increasing the thickness argument of the drawContours-method would help somehow, but unfortunately that does not do the trick. The result looks like this:

[image: Result of my attempt]

I assume, that drawing rectangles over the text area would be more helpful?
Does anyone know a solution and could help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there's such a task, I tend to count pixels along the y-axis, and try to find (large) differences between neighbouring columns. That'd be my complete pipeline:

1. Convert image to grayscale; inverse binary threshold using Otsu's to get white pixels on black background.
2. Do some morphological closing, here using a large vertical line kernel to connect all pixels in the same column.
3. Count all white pixels; calculate the absolute difference between neighbouring columns.
4. Find peaks in that "signal" – manually or, as shown here, by using `scipy.signal.find_peaks`. The peaks identify the start and end of each text column, so the number of text columns is half the number of peaks.

Here's the whole code including some visualization:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     # Only for visualization output
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from skimage import io              # Only for web grabbing images

# Read image from web (attention: RGB order here, scikit-image)
image = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbAeZ.png')

# Convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Inverse binary threshold by Otsu's
thr = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Morphological closing with large vertical line kernel
thr_mod = cv2.morphologyEx(thr, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((image.shape[0], 1)))

# Count white pixels along y-axis
y_count = np.sum(thr_mod / 255, 0)

# Calculate absolute difference between neighbouring x-axis values
y_count_diff = np.abs(np.diff(y_count))

# Find peaks in that "signal"
peaks = signal.find_peaks(y_count_diff, distance=50)[0]

# Number of columns is half the number of found peaks
n_cols = np.int(peaks.shape[0] / 2)

# Text output
print('Number of columns: ' + str(n_cols))

# Some visualization output
plt.figure(0)
plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title('Original image')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(thr_mod, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Thresholded, morphlogically closed image')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(y_count)
plt.plot(peaks, y_count[peaks], 'r.')
plt.title('Summed white pixels along y-axis')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.plot(y_count_diff)
plt.plot(peaks, y_count_diff[peaks], 'r.')
plt.title('Absolute difference in summed white pixels')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The textual output:

```
Number of columns: 3
```

The visualization output:

[image: 1]

Limitations: If your image is tilted, etc. you might get bad results. If you have a lot of (large) images crossing text columns, you also might get bad results. In general, you'll need to adapt the details in the given implementation to meet your actual requirements (no more examples were given).

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
Matplotlib:  3.3.1
NumPy:       1.19.1
OpenCV:      4.4.0
SciPy:       1.5.2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: This works very well! It appears, that I have to change the "distance" parameter for other samples. Determining the "perfect" distance beforehand is nearly impossible, isn't it?

Comment: @MoDo At least, if you have such varying distances between the single text columns, yes. For small gaps between text columns, you'd need to lower the `distance` parameter, causing to many "noise" peaks. In that case, you could try to find "common distances" between all peaks to find the correct text columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could prep the image a little differently before searching for columns. For example you can connect the text horizontally first (with some morphological operation). That will give you contours with a certain height (the heading will be connected vertically as one contour per row and the text in columns will be connected as one contour per row). Then search for all contours and draw bounding rectangles over the ones that are higher than certain value you set (can be calculated or set manually). After that perform the morphological operation again with bigger kernel (horizontal and vertical) so you get all the remaining text connected if it is close together.

Here is an example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("columns.png")  # read image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   # grayscale transform
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # OTSU thresold
kernel = np.ones((5, 10), dtype=np.uint8)  # kernel for first closing procedure (connect blobs in x direction)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)  # closing
cv2.imwrite("closing1.png", closing)
contours = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]  # search for contours

heights = []  # all of contours heights

for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)  # bounding rectangles height, width and coordinates
    heights.append(h)  # append height of one contours

boundary = np.mean(heights, axis=0)  # mean of heights will serve as boundary but
# this will probably not be the case on other samples - you would need to make
# a function to determin this boundary or manualy set it

# iterate through contours
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)  # bounding rectangles height, width and coordinates
    if h > boundary:  # condition - contour must be higher than height boundary
        cv2.rectangle(closing, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 0), -1)  # draw filled rectangle on the closing image

cv2.imwrite("closing1-filled.png", closing)

kernel = np.ones((25, 25), dtype=np.uint8)  # kernel for second closing (connect blobs in x and y direction)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(closing, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)  # closing again

cv2.imwrite("closing2.png", closing)


contours = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]   # search for contours again


# iterate through contours
print("Number of columns: ", len(contours))  # this is the number of columns
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)  # this are height, width and coordinates of the columns
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 3)  # draw bouning rectangle on original image

cv2.imwrite("result.png", img)


cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Number of columns: 3

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works great for the given image! Using it on the other "real" samples I have, however, it seems to be tricky to fine-tune the two kernels and the boundary (as you stated within your code).

Comment: Yes I figured it would be...maybe this can be improved by searching for contours before morphological closing - this can give you heights of all characters and you can adjust the kernel to those heights. For example if avg. height is 10 then the kernel can be (h//2, h) or something like that. Or maybe the average distance between characters can be a factor...you will need to get those values from a few example images and analyze them.