# Count hatched cells per row from scanned image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My main mission is to count the number of hatched cells for each row.
Each cell represents 5 minutes and each row represent an operation.
**Expected output could be a 1D or 2D list, containing all rows in the grid and number of hatched cells on each row.** I know the name of the operation based on the row number. Other documents will have other rows hatched.

But I struggle with mission 1, capture the grid correctly in order to iterate each cell.
I was thinking when I had the grid, I could check if the contour contained mostly black or white and hence catch the hatching.

This far I've managed to import the pdf, deskew the image and crop so only the interesting part is left.
[image: image1]

The numbers above the hatched cells are irrelevant, only noise. This is just 1 of many documents, I reckon the written numbers can show up everywhere.

**Row 12 in this image has 29 hatched cells = 2,42 hours work on that operation**

I reckon my mask-job can be improved, this is what I have so far:

```
image = cv2.imread('result.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (8,8))
bg=cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, se)
out_gray=cv2.divide(gray, bg, scale=255)

thresh = cv2.threshold(out_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh,(5,5),0)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.erode(blur, kernel, iterations=2)
```

Leaves me this:
[image: mask]

I've tried Canny and HoughLines, resulting in only the left side of the grid being captured or making the whole image full of red lines.
I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423841) which has 2 approaches on counting rows and columns in a grid. I came pretty close, but haven't figured out how to ignore the eraser marks, and handle the "non-conformity" of the grid. When iterating it's hard to keep track on where I'm at.
[image: grid and dots]

Maybe a better approach here is to draw/create one perfect row with the right amount columns. Copy row 3 for instance, then copy and offset this x times. I don't know how to approach that though. I can share more of my attempts if interesting, but I've been banging my head for 3 nights and was hoping you guys had some better approach to this problem?

ANY help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show sample expected output?

Comment: @Alderven A simple list would do I guess. [0,0,0,0,13], here meaning row 5 contains 13 hatched cells. I'd like to keep the same number of rows as the real grid. Next document have other rows hatched

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://i2.paste.pics/N1JFN.png) by row?

Comment: @Alderven if you are able to differenciate on that level, perfect. I count 14,5 rows in your picture, but the data will always just be in the ones you pointed out. So 14,5 or 10 rows for that image, whatever's the easiest approach

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is not 100% accurate solution: it is only applicable for the [provided image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DrHY.jpg) and it wrongly marks some cells with numbers as hatched.

The output of the script is the hatched cells count in each row:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 91, 104, 6, 25, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

For illustrative purposes I filled all the hatched cells with red:

[image: output]

Code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

CELL_WIDTH = 21
CELL_HEIGHT = 37
BLACK_PIXELS_THRESHOLD = CELL_WIDTH*CELL_HEIGHT*0.5


def find_hatched_cells(path_to_image):
    results = []
    hatched_cells = 0
    image = Image.open(path_to_image)
    thresh = 200
    fn = lambda x: 255 if x > thresh else 0
    image_bnw = image.convert('L').point(fn, mode='1')
    pixels = image_bnw.load()
    x_max, y_max = image.size
    column = 0
    row = 0
    offset_x = 0
    offset_y = 0
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    while True:
        if row == 0:
            offset_y = 9
        elif row % 7 == 0:
            offset_y -= 1
        elif row % 34 == 0:
            offset_y += 9
        else:
            offset_y += 3
        y = offset_y + row * CELL_HEIGHT
        if y+CELL_HEIGHT > y_max:
            break
        while True:
            if column == 0:
                offset_x += 8
            elif column % 14 == 0:
                offset_x += 5
            elif column % 6 == 0:
                offset_x += 5
            else:
                offset_x += 3
            x = offset_x + column * CELL_WIDTH
            if x+CELL_WIDTH > x_max:
                column = 0
                offset_x = 0
                results.append(hatched_cells)
                hatched_cells = 0
                break
            fill = None
            if is_cell_hatched(pixels, x, y):
                hatched_cells += 1
                fill = 'red'
            draw.rectangle(((x, y), (x + CELL_WIDTH, y + CELL_HEIGHT)), outline='red', fill=fill)
            column += 1
        row += 1

    image.save('output.jpg')
    return results


def is_cell_hatched(pixels, x_start, y_start):
    """ Return True if cell is hatched, None if not hatched """
    black_pixels = 0
    for x in range(x_start, x_start + CELL_WIDTH, 1):
        for y in range(y_start, y_start + CELL_HEIGHT, 1):
            if pixels[x, y] == 0:
                black_pixels += 1
                if black_pixels > BLACK_PIXELS_THRESHOLD:
                    return True


print(find_hatched_cells('image.jpg'))
```

Comment: Wow, I'll test it tonight. Thanks for your long effort!! It seems the cell dims are hard coded. I must ask for more samples to test with. Hopefully I can discard rows with less than 3 hatches. Not sure yet. I started thinking if we collect all widths and heights of openCv's contours, then find the median of both. That would be the cell dims?

Comment: Bah. I've been playing around a little with `cell_width` and `cell_height`, and the offset for row 0. But I guess there's some conversion from OpenCV--> .jpg --> imgur. Your code is flawless for the imgur linked in my question, but doesn't work for the same image while the image is still an OpenCV object, nor when I save to .jpg before using your code. It might work if I'm able to automate the offsets and the cell dimensions?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing actual input data. Can you share few other image samples?

Comment: Here's my current output [using the median of heights and widths](https://i.imgur.com/i7z8uur.jpg), width=35 height =59, but I guess the offset's off.
The actual input is pdf with company logo. I'd rather send it to you privately?

Comment: Seems `width`, `height` and `offsets` requires adjustment. You can send data on my email. It's in a profile.