# How to define a minimum width/height for horizontal and vertical lines when finding the number of rows and columns in a table image with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image: processed image]

I'm attempting to take images of 8.5 x 11" petitions and determine which rows contain something that resembles a signature. I'm assuming that I will be able to isolate each row in an inverted image and count the number of white pixels.

Using [this as a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396925/how-to-find-the-number-of-rows-and-columns-in-a-table-image-with-python-opencv/60423841#60423841), so far in the process I have been able to isolate the tabular portion of the petition that would house signatures. When I attempt to isolate each row and each column however, I also catch portions of the text. And right now, I'm not entirely sure how to define a minimum width or height for a line segment to eliminate the text portioms.

```py
    # load image, convert to grayscale, otsu's threshold
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # find number of rows
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25, 1))
    horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(
        thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2
    )
    cnts = cv2.findContours(horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    rows = 0
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)
        rows += 1

    # find number of columns
    vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 25))
    vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    columns = 0
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)
        columns += 1

    logger.info(f"Rows {rows - 1}")
    logger.info(f"Columns {columns - 1}")

    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Here is the unprocessed image, per @stateMachine's ask.

[image: unprocessed image]

Comment: Please, post samples of the unprocessed images.

Comment: See np.count_nonzeros() to count non-zero pixels for every row or column.  Invert your black boxes/regions so that they are mostly white.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you want to eliminate the little lines coming from the vertical or horizontal parts of the letters. You can use `cv2.arcLength()` to find the perimeter of the detected contours and define your own condition when iterating over the vertical and horizontal contours. See https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html

Comment: the proper maintained link is https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html -- that "opencv24..." site has been dead since 2016 or longer

Comment: since the scan is fairly straight, this would merely require morphology with appropriately wide/tall but slim kernels. or the equivalent filtering in the projections. fmw42 described this (count non-zero pixels in every row/column)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz there are both vertical and horizontal lines in the source image. They seem very thin so basic morphology may cancel some portions of the row and column lines which may mislead when finding number of rows or columns.